# Sankalpam: Replacing terms like 'Jambo dweepe', 'Bharata varshe', etc

Tags: rituals, sankalpa

Should Sankalpam change depending on where it is taken? Which words of the Sankalpam should change if it performed in the US/UK? I refer to terms like Jambo dweepe, Bharatha varshe, etc.

Comment: If you are doing sankalpam for a puja/homa you can take few akshatas(turmeric rice) in your right hand while doing the sankalpa mudra on your right thigh.In this way you can avoid stating your exact location in the sankalpa and still be correct with it.Using akshtas is kind of a shortcut/substitute but it works nonetheless.

Comment: You have to change the nakshatra,  thithi, karana and yoga which must be as be as per sunrise at your location and this will anyway point to your location. Unfortunately there is no tool which can give this info for any location on earth. You will have to do your own math if a panchang is not available for your area. Sankalpam is an important statement and it may be worth the while to get it right. Just think how anyone will reach you if they don't know where you are.

Comment: according to surya siddhanta, entire northern hemisphere is jambudvipa with north pole as mount meru. Thus US will be roughly uttara kuru. This can also be confirmed from harivamsa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, jambu dweepe, bharata varshe, dandakaranye, godavaryah dakshine teere, etc. denote the location.

Here are two pages with substitutes for USA.

https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110406091823AA7IX1K
http://www.ammas.com/q&a/Sankalpa-Mantras-at-USA-vis-a-vis-as-at-India/q/176673

For the USA:

1. Krouncha Dweepe: In the island called Krouncha
2. Ramanaka Varshe: In the region called Ramanaka Varsha
3. Aindra Khande: In the continent called Aindra
4. Prasantha Saagare: Near the Pacific Ocean
5. Pushkara Kshetre: In the locale known as Pushkara
6. Rocky - mickelny Parvatayor Madhye: Between Rockey and Mickelny
   mountains
7. Misissipi- Missouri Ityadhi Aneka Shodasa Jeeva Nadeenam sameepa
   stite: The place that is surrounded by such perenniel rivers like
   Mississipi, Missouri and 16 other rivers

[Here](http://krishna-arpanam.blogspot.in/2010/08/yajur-upakarma-2010aavani-avittam-24th.html) is a page with substitute for UK region.

> Shalmali dhweepe vinyaschitha paschima dhik bage
>   samudra madyasthitha brihadharanya kshethre 
>   London maanagare (replace with any city in the UK you live in)"

Comment: It will be helpful if you can extract the answer from those sites and provide it here.

Answer (score 0):

Krouncha Dweepe: In the island called Krouncha
Ramanaka Varshe: In the region called Ramanaka Varsha

I am not an expert but I think the above two doesn’t represent the continent and country instead they represent a region in universe and earth respectively. And only Bharat Khande represent India. In that case changing the first two doesn't make sense.

http://www.harekrsna.com/sun/editorials/04-13/editorials10050.htm

Answer (score 0):

According to our Shastras, any act done  after  crossing the seas  would  yield no fruit. That is why, "strictly" orthodox people  would hesitate  to take foreign tours/stay there and make it their  homes.Further Bharata  Kanda is considered as "Karma Bhoomi",where any one is rewarded for any religious  act done  as followed by his elders. If however one is particular in observing   rituals, he could  recite the same Mantras  as we believe that the Gods/rivers etc which are invoked  immediately make Their presence .(Gange cha yamunechaive  -----Jaleasmin sannidhim kuru)Only the rivers flowing in / mountains  etc in India are considered  auspicious  and are capable of answering to the prayers of the devout.

Comment: If Bharata Khanda is so pious and people here are only supposed to follow rules, why are other khandas, rivers and mountains created? Does that mean people on other khandas are not supposed to follow rites and rituals? No. What should they recite in their sankalpam? People in other countries should stop rituals? This will defame the Sanatana dharma doesn't uphold at all.

Comment: Which shastras say that we should not cross the Sea? Sri Rama crossed the sea. There were travellers during the time of Mahabharata. Then when was this rule followed?

Comment: @NogShine but he crossed via land that is bridge right

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Now a days too, we are travelling via planes. Isn't that vayuyana? That is also allowed. Isn't it?

Comment: @NogShine yes technically . but we cant consider.ramas case. This is one of the answers based on scripture and belief if you want to take it